# Is there a way I can customize a label that I use often?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin XAML I use this many times:

```
<Label Text="{x:Static local:FontAwesome.FACheck}" FontFamily="FontAwesome" 
   XAlign="Center" FontSize="13" 
   TextColor="#1E90FF" />
```

Is there a way using C# that I can create a custom version of Label and use that so I don't have to keep specifying the Font and other things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a style in C# please see this [link to a xamarin developer guide for global styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/).

Example of the C# code: (sets up a resource dictionary in your App class)

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        var buttonStyle = new Style (typeof(Button)) {
            Setters = {
                ...
                new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty,   Value = Color.Teal }
                new Setter { Property = Button.BackgroundColor,   Value = Color.White }

                // add more setters for the properties that you want to set here
            }
        };

        // add this style into your resource dictionary.
        Resources = new ResourceDictionary ();
        Resources.Add ("buttonStyle", buttonStyle);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You can create controls with these styles in your C# classes:

```
public class ApplicationStylesPageCS : ContentPage
{
    public ApplicationStylesPageCS ()
    {
        ...
        Content = new StackLayout {
            Children = {
                new Button { Text = "These buttons", Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources ["buttonStyle"] },
                new Button { Text = "are demonstrating", Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources ["buttonStyle"] },
                new Button { Text = "application styles", Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources ["buttonStyle"]
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Or alternatively access it in the xaml as a static resource:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Styles.ApplicationStylesPage" Title="Application" Icon="xaml.png">
       <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,0">
            <Button Text="These buttons" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" />
            <Button Text="are demonstrating" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" />
            <Button Text="application style overrides" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 13):

Maybe, you can use a `Style` in your **App.xaml**.

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourAPp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="FACheck" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Static local:FontAwesome.FACheck}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="FontAwesome"/>
                <Setter Property="XAlign" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#1E90FF"/>
            </Style>
       <ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And then in your pages, you just need to use it wherever you need to place this label.

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource FACheck}"/>
```

> In case you want to define your resources in C#

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {

            //Begin - Style code

            var faCheckStyle = new Style(typeof(Label))
            {
                Setters = {
                    new Setter { Property = Label.TextProperty,   Value = FontAwesome.FAChcek },
                    new Setter { Property = Label.FontFamilyProperty, Value = "FontAwesome" },
                    new Setter { Property = Label.XAlignProperty, Value = "FontAwesome" },
                    new Setter { Property = Label.FontSizeProperty, Value = 13 },
                    new Setter { Property = Label.TextColorProperty, Value = Color.FromHex("#1E90FF") }
                 }
            };
            Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
            Resources.Add("FACheck", faCheckStyle);      

            //End Style code
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jesus,  your suggestion looks interesting. I upvoted but didn't yet click on accept. Could I also create this resource in C#?

Comment: Yeah, you can create this in C#, remember that XAML is just syntac sugar over C# code.

Comment: @Alan you can use code instead :) . I updated my answer

Answer (score 6):

Create your class and use it everywhere

```
public class MyAwesomeLabel : Xamarin.Forms.Label
{
    public MyAwesomeLabel()
    {
        FontFamily = "FontAwesome";
        XAlign = Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment.Center; //deprecated BTW
        FontSize = 13;
        TextColor = Color.FromHex(0x1E90FF);
        //etc
    }
}
```